# use PowerShell to render CSV data to text field so that its formatted like a spreadsheet

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

Is there a cmdlet | method in PowerShell that would allow the creation of text formatting so that CSV data looks like a spreadsheet (with rows and columns) inside the console?

An example of what I am looking for is found in this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261816/1870833

```
+-------------------------------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+
|             Name              |    Created     |        filePath        | Extension |
+-------------------------------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+
|         test2                 | 3/6/2013 19:21 | X:\Test\test2          | Folder    |
|         Results.csv           | 3/6/2013 19:51 | X:\Test\Results.csv    | .csv      |
|         test3                 | 3/6/2013 19:21 | X:\Test\test2\test3    | Folder    |
|         New Text Document.txt | 3/6/2013 19:21 | X:\Test\test2\New.txt  | .txt      |
+-------------------------------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+
```

I know that there is an `Out-GridView` cmdlet but it doesn't allow for copy and pasting of headers and parts of rows.

Comment: You mean like `Import-Csv path\to\input.csv |Format-Table`?

Comment: ahh good question, I could have been clearer... 
That gets me a bit closer, as I have been tinkering with the Import-Csv path\to\input.csv |Format-Table -AutoSize -wrap so that text isn't truncated. I'd still like to see if there's a way to get the visual separation of text fields using + - | to draw the table.

Comment: You might want to play around with the concepts shown here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/draw-boxes-and-lines-in-the-windows-powershell-console-host/

Comment: With this custom [`Format-Csv`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Format-Csv/1.0.0) command: `Import-Csv .\input.csv |Format-Table -Delimiter '|'` (it doesn't do the outer and horizontal lines as will make it unreadable for `ConvertFrom-Csv`/`Import-Csv`)