# PowerShell search recursively for files and folder which the name contains "..."

Tags: powershell

I need help to create a script that can save my life.

My backup software got it wrong because I misdesigned my backup plan and I have lots of named files; filename or folder name (2) (encoding conflict).

I would like to recursively search my network share to find folders and files with "(encode conflict)" in their name and first export them for verification.

Then, if all goes well, I would like to move them to another place while keeping the folder's hierarchy and that's where I stuck.

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '\\?\E:\Network Shares\Commun' -Recurse  -Filter "*(encode*" #| move-item -Destination 'C:\Users\Desktop\Conflits\'
```

For the export I found the script here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261816/19493679

Thanks to OP

The files from my test are moving without folder's and file's hierarchy ...

Can you help me please ? :)

Comment: I used LiteralPath cause I have file path that easily exceeds 260 characters ...

Comment: I think you are close to the solution. Maybe you should try something like this:

`Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '\\?\E:\Network Shares\Commun' -Recurse  -Filter "*(encode*" | ForEach-Object {  Move-Item "$($_.fullname)" 'C:\Users\Desktop\Conflits\'   }`

Comment: @ExcèsRefusé This still doesn't replicate the source directory structure. Some things in PS are harder than they should be, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Move-Item` doesn't know about the directory structure, it just gets paths fed one by one from `Get-ChildItem`. For preserving directory structure, `Move-Item` would have to know a common base path, but there is currently no way to specify one.

So I've created a helper function `New-DestinationPath` that can be chained in between `Get-ChildItem` and `Move-Item` (or `Copy-Item`). The function creates the destination directory structure and outputs the source path and the fully resolved destination path.

```sh
Function New-DestinationPath {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Alias('Fullname', 'PSPath')]
        [String] $Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
        [String] $CommonPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=1)]
        [String] $Destination
    )
    process {
        # Temporarily change current directory -> base directory for Resolve-Path -Relative
        Push-Location $CommonPath
        try {
            # Resolve input path relative to $CommonPath (current directory)  
            $relativePath = Resolve-Path $Path -Relative
        }
        finally {
            Pop-Location  # Restore current directory
        }

        # Resolve full target file path and directory
        $targetPath   = Join-Path $Destination $relativePath
        $targetDir    = Split-Path $targetPath -Parent

        # Create target dir if not already exists (-Force).
        $null = New-Item $targetDir -ItemType Directory -Force
       
        # Output the full source and destination paths (for use with Copy-Item or Move-Item) 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Path = $Path
            Destination = $targetPath
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```sh
$searchPath = '\\?\E:\Network Shares\Commun'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $searchPath -Recurse -File |
  Where-Object Fullname -like '*(encode*' |
  New-DestinationPath -CommonPath $searchPath -Destination 'C:\Users\Desktop\Conflits' -WhatIf |
  Move-Item -LiteralPath { $_.Path } -Destination { $_.Destination } -WhatIf
```

- By using the common parameter `-WhatIf` the functions only output what they *would* do. Remove both `-WhatIf` arguments when you have confirmed that the right paths are used.
- In the `Move-Item` call we are using [delay-bind scriptblocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) to avoid a `ForEach-Object` command. Using the automatic variable `$_` we can directly refer to the output of the previous command in the pipeline (`New-DestinationPath`).

Comment: Hello Thanks you for answering me !
It doesnt work for example with the Get-ChildItem I got this file in the long list : "Case LD2165 2021 (2)(encode conflict) - 2021-12-20T020640.748080Z.pdf"
With the script linked I get 4628 files and I guess a lot of folders which are ignored for now but I would like to move files and folder containing (encode conflict).
The what if returns me : WhatIf: "Move file" operation in progress on target "Item: \\?\E:\Network Shares\Commun\SPOOL95.INI Destination: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Conflicts\SPOOL95.INI". which doesnt even contains "(encode.."

Comment: @zett42 :) - thanks for fixing your answer.

Comment: Its incredible !
Its verry complexe I would never accomplish that !
it works almost like I would like from my tests it doesnt move folders which the names contain (encode but it moves the files in that folder.

Comment: @Pristep I've removed `-Filter` and added a `Where-Object` command to filter on the whole path. So this should move any file that contains `*(encode*` in the full path, e. g. `\\?\E:\Network Shares\Commun\Foo(encode)\bar.txt` or `\\?\E:\Network Shares\Commun\Foo\bar(encode).txt`

Comment: @zett42 Its awesome I am gonna give a try with the whatif on my env.
But I think you resolved my issue

Comment: @Zett42 I have extracted 37gb of files but at the end I have some errors :
Move-Item: Unable to find part of path.
To Line:45 character: 3
+ Move-Item -LiteralPath { $_.Path } -Destination { $_.Destination }
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: WriteError: (\\?\E:\Network ...947.782402Z.jpg:FileInfo) [Move-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
I am almost sure its due to long paths ..

Comment: I have found this file via windows search : 870905_Trennwand_Sicherheitst┬Àr_01(encode conflict) - 2022-08-30T011026.599113Z.jpg (>.<) I think its tricky

Comment: @Pristep What is the problem, `Get-ChildItem` doesn't find the file?

Comment: @zett42 I think so anyway I have discovered new issue with the backup ... I have also *(case conflit)* I have modified your script it worked well for a lot of files but i have some that didnt get found ... I dunno why there is an exemple this is a directory :
E:\Network Shares\Commun\DOSSIER COMMUN\OFFRES EN COMMUN\PROVINCE Grièle 4000 à 4990\4650 - Collège Royal Marie-Thérèse(case conflict) - 2021-09-17T011038.424673Z\

As you can see its like powershell is ignoring some folders / directory ...

Comment: @zett42 even if I set the searchpath with "E:\Network Shares\Commun\DOSSIER COMMUN\OFFRES EN COMMUN\PROVINCE Grièle 4000 à 4990" it doesn't find anything
But if i remove the -file after the search path it finds it but not sure if its the best idea ...

Comment: @Pristep If you can't find a solution, I suggest you ask a new question. Current question has been answered, new problem could be related to character encoding of file path.

Comment: @zett42 done ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73797347/powershell-command-doesnt-find-files-folder