# Powershell command doesnt find files/folder

Tags: powershell, path, special-characters

Hello I am facing an issue with a script given here by @zett42

[PowerShell search recursively for files and folder which the name contains "..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73773334/powershell-search-recursively-for-files-and-folder-which-the-name-contains)

```
$DesktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$searchPath = '\\?\E:\Network Shares\Commun'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $searchPath -Recurse -File |
Where-Object Fullname -like '*(case*' |
New-DestinationPath -CommonPath $searchPath -Destination "$home\desktop\conflits" -WhatIf | Move-Item -LiteralPath { $_.Path } -Destination { $_.Destination } -WhatIf
```

For example there is a complete path ;

```
E:\Network Shares\Commun\DOSSIER COMMUN\OFFRES EN COMMUN\ENGRAM 5000\5520 - Ecole Communale drièle**(case conflict)** - 2022-09-03T011223.317039Z\(subfolders ...)
```

But the command doesn't find files / folders, my network share contains a lot of long paths.
And it contains also some special characters like éèà etc.
Can you help me to adapt the command to find the unfound files/folders please ?
Thanks by advance :)

Comment: Use the `-force`, Luke

Comment: @zett42 done :) sorry :)

Comment: @Cid Best comment evar.

Comment: @Cide it didnt work thanks you for your support, vader.

Comment: It could be because of the double usage of `-WhatIf` : `New-DestinationPath ... -WhatIf | Move-Item ... -WhatIf`. The first `-WhatIf` outputs a string

Comment: @Cid no its not the problem I have tried to remove the whatif...
But if I remove the -file the strange case it founds the ignored folders but I only get the folder and not the files in it.