# Powershell: Copy files and directories based upon a list of wildcards. Wildcards contain directories

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a list of files and folders from a source directory structure to a destination directory. The directory structure shall remain intact. I want to filter the source directory tree using wildcards, but the filter may contain partial paths with folders, files and wildcards. Basically, I want to achieve something similar to this beautiful and efficient bash snippet:

```
echo "\
CMake/somefilepattern* \
include/somefile.h \
source/somefolder/* \
" | tr -s " " "\n" | rsync -amv --include="*/" --include-from=- --exclude="*" "/path/to/source/" "/path/to/destination/"
```

Just in powershell (7.x). All my attempts with `Copy-Item` and `-Filter` or `-Include` failed because these parameters do only work on filenames.

Comment: Have a look at the ```Compare-Object``` cmdlet? There you can compare two 'gci $dir1 $dir2' where you process the delta? Maybe combined with a for loop?

Comment: You can use `Where-Object` filtering similar to this solution (just replace `Move-Item` by `Copy-Item`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/73773804/7571258

Comment: Also, the native [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) command might be easier to use.

Comment: @zett42 good suggestion, but if I am not mistaken, robocopy has the same limitation as Copy-Item, that is, the filter must not contain folders.

Comment: @RichardW It looks you are right. Only the exclude options (`/xf` and `/xd`) accept paths.